# Ext.Net 2.x removing Gridfilters

Tags: extjs, ext.net

I try to remove all Filters in a Gridpanel (dynamically created, so Filtername is not known).
If i use

```
Ext.getCmp('Gridpanel').getStore().clearFilter();
```

it removes the Filter from results but the Filters are still visible like they were not removed. I might have to mention that i use     `locked:true`    since that already created some issues with configs because Grid is split...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

take alokk at this one 
which same as with u problem

```
http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?17292-CLOSED-How-to-clear-GridPanel-filters-on-the-client
```

[how remove group and filter](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?6571-how-remove-group-and-filter)

[menu config](http://dotnetinside.com/en/type/Ext.Net/GridFilter/2.5.1.24988)

there ,there is  a virtual, method called active (boolean),try this

Comment: doesn't work in Version 2.x - Firebug says "TypeError: panel.filters is undefined"